# 2 questions about ImageButtons being laggy and not fitting

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-imagebutton

So, I made an XML file of a fragment that contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/flourbutton"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
        <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sugara"
        android:id="@+id/flour"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is:

1. I have navigation drawer in my app and it makes it very laggy...probably the pictures...what can I do?
2. Right now the buttons have white borders around them but not between them
   like shown below:
   [buttons problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmnMq.png)
   how can i fit them to the entire layout width and height?

Thank you all!!

Java code:

```
package com.example.matancohen.sg50;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.MessageQueue;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    displayView(R.id.nav_home);


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


private void displayView(int itemId) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new Article();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Recipes:
            fragment = new Recipes();
            break;

    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    displayView(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Is this the only layout in your application? Or do you include it into another? If yes, check the parent layout for margin/padding attributes. If not, check if your styles do not have margin/padding specified.

Comment: I LOVE YOU! genius!!!
what about the lagged nav drawer?

Comment: I do not know bout the drawer, but I would try to remove style and replace app:srcCompat with android:src. Try what it does

Comment: Did nothing :\
damn

Comment: you have to post your java code so that other can see what's wrong with it (lagged).

Comment: Edited @AbidKhan

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't initialize `DrawerLayout` on each item select. Do it once in onCreate and just use it like `drawer.closeDrawers();`.

Secondly I don't see any huge data in your fragment but for fragment where you have huge data you can replace fragment using `Runnable`. So the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect below is how to achieve it.

```
private void displayView(int itemId) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new Article();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Recipes:
            fragment = new Recipes();
            break;

    }

    if(fragment != null) {
            Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                            android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                }
            };
            mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
            drawer.closeDrawers();
        }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you face problems

Comment: man you really need to watch [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) then

Comment: Are you kiddin me?
I know what it means but its completley changing my code!
can you put it inside and write again?

Comment: It didn't help :(

Comment: ok. Just made the images on the drawable smaller and the lags just poofed away